# React child component re-renders even when props do not change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render, react-props, setstate

I am trying to create a chart in D3 inside a React component. Whenever I change the state in my parent component, the child gets re-rendered even though it's props do not change or are affected in any way by the setState. I have even tried to use React.memo on the child component but it still gets re-rendered. How can I avoid the re-render if the props have not changed.

**PSEUDOCODE**

```js
  /* Parent component */

  function parentComponent(props) {
     const [a, setA] = useState({})
     
     function customEventHandler() {
       setA(); // This cause child to re-render
     }

     return (
       // Some rendering based on the value of a
       // Some custom event handler 
       <ChildComponent config={{}} />
     ) 
  }

  /* Child component [D3 based component with useRef] */
  function childComponent = React.memo((props) => {})
```

CodeBox link here https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-fast-unlzq?file=/src/App.js

**ISSUE**: The graphs get re-rendered every time the input text changes.

Comment: Are you passing in an object literal or an anonymous function to your ChildComponent?

Comment: It is an object literal

Comment: That is your problem then. An object defined in the render function's scope will be a different object (in terms of a new object reference) and therefore be recognized as a prop change in React.

Comment: I changed the code sandbox and it now works as expected. That was really silly on my part. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem at all! Glad to help.